# loading the main form given two forms in c sharp

Tags: c#

is there a way i can get my main form which is form1 to show after form 2 has loaded??i created two forms form 1 is the main form and form 2 is the login form i want when a user has correct creditials form 1 should load automatically
this is form 2 code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username1 = "Richard";
            string password1 = "Peugeot";

            if (this.textBox1.Text == username1 && this.textBox2.Text == password1)
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome Richard!", "Welcome");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password", "Bad credentials");
        }
```

this is form1 code

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);

            sb.AppendLine("Operation System Information");
            sb.AppendLine("----------------------------");
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Name = {0}", OSVersionInfo.Name));
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Edition = {0}", OSVersionInfo.Edition));
            if (OSVersionInfo.ServicePack!=string.Empty)
                sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Service Pack = {0}", OSVersionInfo.ServicePack));
            else
                sb.AppendLine("Service Pack = None");
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Version = {0}", OSVersionInfo.VersionString));
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("ProcessorBits = {0}", OSVersionInfo.ProcessorBits));
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("OSBits = {0}", OSVersionInfo.OSBits));
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("ProgramBits = {0}", OSVersionInfo.ProgramBits));

            textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
```

this is the program.cs code

```
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form2());
        }
    }
```

i want form 1 to load automatically after form2 thanks in advance

Comment: `new Form1().Show()` ?

Comment: i do not understand your question

Comment: oooooooooooh i get it let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh , I think this is what you need

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username1 = "Richard";
            string password1 = "Peugeot";

            if (this.textBox1.Text == username1 && this.textBox2.Text == password1)
             {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome Richard!", "Welcome");
                Form1 frm = new Form1();
                frm.Show();
                this.Hide(); //If you want to hide the log in form after form1 has loaded
             }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password", "Bad credentials");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the login credentials are verified and are correct, you can use the following:

```
Hide();
Form1 mainForm = new Form1();
mainForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you're after here is a way of showing form1 only if the user is validated?
If so, just show the form here:

```
if (this.textBox1.Text == username1 && this.textBox2.Text == password1)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    form1.Show();
    // close form2?  
}
else
 ...
```

You might want to keep a counter and if the user doesn't get the password/username combination right within x attempts, just unload form2 (i.e. from the else).

Answer (score 0):

If `Form1` is your main `Form` it may be a better option to load `Form1` first and show `Form2` as a dialog, if the `DialogResult` from `Form2` is not `OK` exit the application else continue.

```
public Form1()
{
    if (new Form2().ShowDialog() != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Close();
    }
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Form2 button event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username1 = "Richard";
    string password1 = "Peugeot";

    if (this.textBox1.Text == username1 && this.textBox2.Text == password1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome Richard!", "Welcome");
        DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password", "Bad credentials");
        DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No;
    }
}
```